# How to pass input$id as variable in a string expression (formula) within a shiny app

Tags: r, parsing, shiny, google-sheets-formula, eval

Using `googlesheets4` it is possible to remove a specific row with this code (here for row 7):

`range_delete(ss, range = "7:7")`

In a shiny app I want to pass input$id (which is 7 in my case) to this formula:

This works:

```
  # delete row 7
  range_delete(ss, range = "7:7")
```

I have tried:
Works not:

```
range_delete(ss, range = eval(parse(text="input$id:input$id")))
```

Also tried:
Works not

```
range_delete(ss, range = quote("input$id:input$id"))
```

Gives error:

```
Warning: Error in : `range` doesn't appear to be a range in A1 notation, a named range, or
a sheet name:
x input$id:input$id
  [No stack trace available]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: May be this one: `range_delete(ss, range = sprintf("%d:%d", input$id, input$id))`

Comment: Thank you Stefano. I will try it as far as I am on my desktop computer in the evening. But looks good.

Comment: Also `paste(input$id, input$id, sep = ":")` should work, or?